# Handle multiple remote notifications while app is active - swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, handle

I would like to know the workflow to handle multiple remote notifications received at the same time while the app is active (opened, running ..).

The best option for me would be to display the notification in the notification center but I heard it is not recommended by Apple, is there someone who already did it without having problem during the submission ?

The second option would be to handle all these notifications, display an alert for the first one, and then ... I don't know how to handle the second one, third one etc ..

**EDIT:** The thing I'm trying to do is to not spam the user with alert if for example if he receives 45 notifications in one minute, then I would like to display every notifications in the notification center (where all notifications of all applications are displayed, I'm not sure about the name), and each time he clicks on one notification, I could display the alert or display the right screen etc, do you know if this is possible ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is heavily based on what you want to do with them. Usually an app receives a notification and just updates a **number** (badge)... I mean: new notification --> number + 1 --> show in the app. What's your problem? If you need to get notifications in different viewcontrollers in your app, the `NSNotificationCenter` is extremely useful. **Do not** get guided by that "I heard that...", instead read the Apple docs. I would create a class named `NotificationManager` or something like that with a singleton. Then pass the notification to that class and use the notification center to inform. Easy.

Comment: In that class I would implement methods like: `sharedManager` (singleton), `clearNotifications`, `didOpenAppWithLaunchOptions:`, `didReceiveRemoteNotification:andApplication:`, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:andApplication:`, `updateNotifications`, etc. Basically get info from the notification, get some other info I need (for example, from a webservice), format it in an array or dictionary and then pass it to the rest of the app using `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments !!

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is to not spam the user with alert if for example he receives 45 notifications in one minute I would like to display every notifications in the notification center (where all notifications of all applications are displayed, I'm not sure it is the right name), and each time he clicks on one notification, I could display the alert or display the right screen etc, do you know if this is possible ?

Comment: That's pretty much server-side other than iOS side. Enqueue all the notifications in your server and make a timer (probably using **CRON** or something like that) and send the notifications every 1 minute or so. Instead of sending all them 45, count them, send only one notification with `You have 45 messages/likes/whatever` and then clear the list. The importance of notifications is that they are **not** made for getting them all (in fact, lots of them get lost in their way). Their purpose is to alert the user that **something happened**, not to fetch data, messages and stuff. That's extra.

Comment: Ok thank you, this actually help me solved my problem :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)